# Vectorisation of for-loops for matrix subset comparisons

Tags: r, vectorization, subset

Say I have a numeric matrix of scores for a given number of samples, ID1, ID2, and so on. For each sample, and each observation, there are three scores labelled A, B, and C.

```
# Mock data
foo <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(150, rate=.1), ncol=15))
foo <- rbind(c("A","B","C"), foo)
colnames(foo) <- rep(paste("ID", c(1:5), sep=""), rep(3, 5))
foo[1:5,1:6]

               ID1            ID1.1            ID1.2              ID2            ID2.1             ID2.2
1                A                B                C                A                B                 C
2 5.56521375011492 38.8443598688996 8.40060065458429 3.04018635302782 15.7668948165121  33.2867358608131
3 1.15913633337383 1.77594455424696  7.8426102303155 10.2102611125281 1.37656751088798  10.8752515162797
4 19.2305917284431 1.17383518721908 12.1561537865074 13.8317152201654 7.51959749455464  29.5795920474415
5    6.26116017811 1.45891858730465 26.5209942103679 1.67936608195305  18.366959299052 0.121995760127902
```

For each observation (row) in the matrix, I need to check the three scores listed for each sample and find the maximum. Once I have found the maximum, I write the score's label (A, B or C) into a new matrix, which is one third the size of the original.

I am currently performing this using nested `for-loop`s, which obviously is terribly inefficient due to the amount of indexing required. Nevertheless, here is the outline of my current implementation:

```
# Result matrix
res <- matrix(nrow=(nrow(foo) - 1), ncol=(ncol(foo) / 3))

# Iterate over observations
for (i in 2:nrow(foo)) {
    # Count columns in the row to track sample ID
    col = 1
    for (j in 1:ncol(res)) {
        index <- which.max(foo[i,col:(col + 2)])
        if (index == 1) {
            label <- "A"
        } else if (index == 2) {
            label <- "B"
        } else {
            label <- "C"
        }
        # Store labels of the maximum score for that observation and sample
        res[i - 1,j] <- label
        # Move to the next sample ID
        col <- col + 3
    }
}
```

So, I am trying to vectorise at least part of this process to improve performance. My attempts thus far have all revolved around the idea of getting the first column index for each sample, in order to divide the total work by three, as such:

```
# Get first index of each sample
ind <- seq(from=1, to=ncol(foo), by=3)
# Get index range of each sample as a list
ind <- lapply(ind, function(x) {
    seq(from=x, to=(x + 2), by=1)
})
```

This gives me a list of the indices at which each sample occurs, but I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Any functions that I write to make use of `which.max` invariably come back to iterating over rows, then iterating over the members of the `ind` list.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Are there vectorised functions which I'm overlooking, or would `lapply` be a better fit than the nested `for-loop`s?

Comment: Question - why is the `c(A, B, C)` row part of `foo` (which causes all your rows to be coerced to characters)? -- try your sample code, it doesn't work because of this.

Comment: I guess this format is difficult to work with. A basic approach would be to turn your "data.frame" to a format with 4 columns (No_observation, sample, id, value; e.g. [4 B ID3 3.17]) or 5 columns (No_observation, id, value_A, value_B, value_C) and use tools like `aggregate` and `xtabs` on this format.

Comment: @voidHead perhaps you could use Rcpp to make the loops faster. However there is a probably vectorized solution in R.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee good catch, the sample code wasn't working due to an error with indexing, though. It should work now, regardless of character coercion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should really not `rbind` the labels `c('A', 'B', 'C')` to your dataframe, because this causes all the numbers in `foo` to become strings, not numbers! Keep them separate (you never use that first row of foo in your code, anyway).

I can think of a few ways to do this, and I'm sure there are others I haven't thought of too.

First I'll make a matrix that's like yours but just without the `c('A', 'B', 'C')` so that my numbers are actually numbers, not characters.

```
foo <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(150, rate=.1), ncol=15))
labels <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
colnames(foo) <- make.unique(rep(paste("ID", c(1:5), sep=""), rep(3, 5)))
```

---

First method I can think of (pretty direct) - flatten your dataframe to a vector and find the max of every 3 values, then reshape back into the shape you wanted `res` to be.

```
foo.flat <- as.vector(t(foo)) # transpose as R is column-wise and I want row-wise
# split(foo.flat, ceiling(1:length(foo.flat)/3)) # splits into chunks of 3, so:
ms <- vapply(split(foo.flat, ceiling(1:length(foo.flat)/3)),
             which.max, # function to apply to each chunk of 3
             -1, # template value for vapply
             USE.NAMES=F)
```

Now just convert 1 to A, 2 to B, 3 to C and reshape back into matrix (`res`):

```
res <- matrix(labels[ms], byrow=T, ncol=ncol(foo)/3)
```

---

Second method I can think of - reshape your matrix to long form (`reshape2`) and use `plyr` to do the calculation for each (row, ID). (maybe more elegant but more confusing?, up to you)

```
foo$observation <- 1:nrow(foo)
library(reshape2)
foo.long <- melt(foo, id='observation', variable.name='ID')
# fix IDs, i.e. ID1.2 --> ID1 etc
foo.long$ID <- gsub('\\.[1-9]+$', '', foo.long$ID)
# > head(foo.long[order(foo.long$observation, foo.long$ID),])
#    observation  ID     value
# 1            1 ID1 15.751959
# 11           1 ID1 20.386724
# 21           1 ID1  9.423799
# 31           1 ID2  4.560623
# 41           1 ID2  1.140642
# 51           1 ID2 37.009728
```

`observation` is just the row each number came from, with `ID` being the ID.
Now for each (observation, variable) find the index of the maximum.

```
library(plyr)
intermediate <- ddply(foo.long, .(observation, ID), function (x) which.max(x$value))
> head(intermediate)
#  observation  ID V1
# 1           1 ID1  2
# 2           1 ID2  3
# 3           1 ID3  3
# 4           1 ID4  2
# 5           1 ID5  3
# 6           2 ID1  1
```

Now just reshape the V1 column back to a matrix (converting indices to your labels)

```
res <- matrix(labels[intermediate$V1], byrow=T, ncol=floor(ncol(foo)/3)))
```

You could do something similar with `data.table` as well which could be faster depending on the size of your matrix.

Comment: Great use of transposition in combination with `vapply` here. I've implemented the first transformation in this manner and it works very well. The problem then, is that the three labels differ for each row of the original matrix. I'm currently trying to define then assign the labels row-wise using `ddply`, but it seems impractically slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh. I suppose you could use `mapply` with `split(foo.flat, ...)` and `split(my.labels, ...)` and instead of using `which.max`, you'd do `function(values, labels) labels[which.max(values)]` or something. Basically chunking up your labels too and iterating them using one of the *applys. (You could alternatively `vapply` along `seq(1, length(foo.flat), by=3)` and do fancy-footing with `labels[i:(i+2)][which.max(foo.flat[i:(i+2)])]`.

Comment: I ended up using a variant on the `vapply` tricksies. Working in the flat form was much easier than the alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Suggested data structure

First, having headings and sub-headings isn't really ideal for
automation and is prone to problems. I'd break it up to a list of IDs,
each of which is a dataframe of the three runs. (We'll add the `ID1`
naming convention at the end, if it's necessary.)

```
set.seed(1234)
foo1 <- lapply(1:5,
               function(id) data.frame(matrix(rexp(30, rate=.1), ncol=3)))
head(foo1[[1]], n=3)
##           X1       X2        X3
## 1 25.01758605 18.80077 19.962787
## 2  2.46758883 15.96105  7.283865
## 3  0.06581957 16.58662  3.835416
```

This greatly facilitates the `*apply` family of functions. This first
batch operates on each list element and converts it into a single column

```
foo2 <- lapply(foo1, function(ff) apply(ff, 1, which.max))
head(foo2, n=2)
## [[1]]
##  [1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3
## 
## [[2]]
##  [1] 3 2 2 3 3 2 1 1 3 3
```

Now it's easy enough to combine these into one data.frame:

```
foo3 <- Reduce(cbind, foo2)
head(foo3, n=3)
##      init        
## [1,]    1 3 1 2 3
## [2,]    2 2 3 2 3
## [3,]    2 2 2 2 2
```

Lastly, let's put it back into letter-mode (if you must), and add the
column names (again, if you must):

```
foo4 <- apply(foo3, c(1,2), function(x) c('A','B','C')[x])
colnames(foo4) <- paste0('ID', seq.int(ncol(foo4)))
head(foo4, n=3)
##      ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
## [1,] "A" "C" "A" "B" "C"
## [2,] "B" "B" "C" "B" "C"
## [3,] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
```

### Your data structure

Assuming we must use it, I'll still break it up neatly into
element-size, and continue with the `*apply` stuff:

```
# Mock data
set.seed(1234)
foo5 <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(150, rate=.1), ncol=15))
head(foo5[,1:5], n=3)
##            X1       X2        X3          X4        X5
## 1 25.01758605 18.80077 19.962787  4.34543487  1.291397
## 2  2.46758883 15.96105  7.283865  0.09091824 20.895804
## 3  0.06581957 16.58662  3.835416 16.10286033 25.188229
```

Instead of trying to loop through everything, how about subsetting the
data.frame into smaller chunks:

```
foo6 <- lapply(seq(1, ncol(foo5), by=3),
               function(ii) foo5[,ii:(ii+2)])
```

... and then use the rest of the code above to do the rest.

```
foo7 <- Reduce(cbind,
               lapply(foo6, function(ff) apply(ff, 1, which.max)))
foo8 <- apply(foo7, c(1,2), function(x) c('A','B','C')[x])
colnames(foo8) <- paste0('ID', seq.int(ncol(foo8)))
head(foo8, n=3)
##      ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
## [1,] "A" "C" "A" "B" "C"
## [2,] "B" "B" "C" "B" "C"
## [3,] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
```

(The way I work some of these problems, I'd really like it if SO
allowed Rmd files or at least full-up markdown.)

Comment: Nice writeup. I might rewrite the last part as: `\`dim<-\`(LETTERS[foo3], dim(foo3))` instead of using the `apply`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, and eventually I intentionally stuck with `c('A','B','C')` in case it wasn't the letters themselves as much as a placeholder (as many do when they're trying to make a simple and reproducible question). Your use of `dim<-` is impressive, though; I wanted something smooth and opted for the easy way out.

Comment: I tried a similar approach using `lapply` a few days ago, but found that outside of the toy problem, it was too slow. Converting the indices back into letters is, unfortunately, essential, though I absolutely agree that processing without the sub-heading is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem seems hard because you have your data in wide-wide format. I would use `reshape2` first, then it doesn't seem so hard, we can just use which.max to do the work:

```
foo <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(150, rate=.1), ncol=15))
foo <- rbind(c("A","B","C"), foo)
colnames(foo) <- paste0("ID", rep(1:5, each=3), rep(LETTERS[1:3], times=5))

require(reshape2)

#make an id variable
foo$id <- 1:nrow(foo)

foo.melt <- melt(foo, "id")

#take apart ID1A into two seperate variables
foo.melt$num <- rep(1:5, each=3)[foo.melt$variable]
foo.melt$rep <- rep(1:3, times=5)[foo.melt$variable]

res <- do.call(rbind, by(foo.melt, interaction(foo.melt$id, foo.melt$num),
       function(x) {
           id <- x[1,"id"]
           num <- x[1,"num"]
           #which.max gets us the index of the max, look it up and get a letter.
           type <- LETTERS[x[which.max(x$value), "rep"]]
           data.frame(id=id, num=num, type=type);
       }
       )
)
dcast(res, id~num)
```

Giving us:

```
R>dcast(res, id~num)
Using type as value column: use value.var to override.
   id 1 2 3 4 5
1   1 A C A A B
2   2 C A B C C
3   3 C B A A B
4   4 B C C A C
5   5 A C B B C
6   6 A B A C B
7   7 B B B A A
8   8 A C A A B
9   9 A B C C B
10 10 A B C A B
```